# Mysql query LEFT JOIN unexpected result

Tags: mysql, select, join

mysql SELECT query with left join is not producing the result I am expecting.
I hope someone can show me or point me to the right direction,

I am trying to build a query where I get all the users name from the "users" table and 
fetch the sum of all the time they spent for a particular date from the master table. I've used the left join but I am not getting the result as expected.

```
 SUM(m.time_spent) as sum_total_time
 FROM master as m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
   WHERE m.date_created >= '2016-05-09'
  AND m.date_created <= '2016-05-13'
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY name
```

master table

```
master_id       user_id         time_spent               date_created
1                     1              40                   2016-05-01
2                     2             36                   2016-05-02
3                     3              56                   2016-05-03
4                     2             33                   2016-05-03
5                     1              32                   2016-05-05
nth                 nth       nth number                    nth date
```

users table

```
user_id            first_name            last_name
1                     James                 Green
2                     Robert                 Cox 
3                    Andy                    Roger
etc                   etc                    etc
```

I want the output result should look like this:

```
user_id       Name               sum_total_time

1               James Green          62
2               Robert Cox           69
3               Andy Roger           56
4               Brian Harper         0
5               Angel Lee            0
6               Andrew Martin        55
..... 
.....
Nth Name                             Nth value
```

Comment: You use `WHERE m.date_created >= '2016-05-09'`  And your date_created is less than this date. Also what is  AND m.date_created  ??? Where is condition?

Comment: 3 things: 1) The table on the left side should be users (or just switch it to a RIGHT join) and 2) the sum needs to `coalesce(m.time_spent,0)`  3) move the where clause details to the join as they need to be applied before the data is joined.

Comment: what result you are getting instead?

Comment: @xObert, as a matter of fact, the coalesce is not necessary, NULLs do affect the SUM. SImilarly, conditions in the `where` clause and in the `on` clause have the same effect (moreover, internally they are treated as a single list of conditions). Good point on the `RIGHT JOIN` though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select data directly from the master table, group by user and calculate the sum. Then you can join this result with the user table to get all the information about the user.

Comment: How do I write the query for that?

Answer (score 0):

Could be date conversione issue ..

```
 SUM(m.time_spent) as sum_total_time
 FROM master as m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
   WHERE m.date_created >=STR_TO_DATE( '2016-05-09', '%Y-%m-%d)
```

and/or you have also incomplete sql

```
SUM(m.time_spent) as sum_total_time
 FROM master as m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
   WHERE m.date_created >= '2016-05-09'
  AND m.date_created  // this condition don't match with nothing.. 
                      // could be you forgot a part
```

Update 1
If you want user totale then

```
   select u.id,   u.name, SUM(m.time_spent) as sum_total_time
   FROM master as m
   Inner  JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
   WHERE m.date_created >=STR_TO_DATE( '2016-05-09', '%Y-%m-%d)
   AND m.date_created <= =STR_TO_DATE('2016-05-13'', '%Y-%m-%d)
   Group by u.id
```

Comment: This only gives me matching rows. Where as I want to fetch all users from users table who has values in masters (sum_total_time) and who has no values(NULL).

Comment: I've solved the problem by adding the condition on "LEFT OUTER JOIN ON" rather then using WHERE clause. Thanks anyway.